# Extend a class with a parent class after the object is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

First off, I know the following use case looks unlikely. But I have a bit of an edge case situation where an Inherited class will create it's super class when saved. Then afterwards, I might want to extend the class again for its functions.

**Situation**

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  enum type: %i[foo baz]

  def print_report_name
    if self.foo?
      self.extend_class Foo::Report # <-- made up function that I need
    end
    pp self.name
  end
end

module Foo
  class Report < ::Report
    def initialize
      self.type = :foo
    end

    def print_report_name
      self.name = "Foo #{self.name}"
      super
    end
  end
end
```

**Script**

```
report = Foo::Report.new(name: 'bar')
report.save!
# Other place in the code
report = Report.find_by(name: 'bar')
report.print_report_name
# Expected outcome: "Foo bar"
```

Basically I want to elevate the class functions to a parent class from within the object.

I hope this is clear. Please correct me to use the right terminology and I'll update the question.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are going to achieve? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Do you know about polymorphic associations? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: It quite complex to explain really. I generate say 10 reports from files, Some files are `Foo` reports, others are different again. In the end I merge these reports together into 1 big Report. Then the above situation comes into place, that if all 10 reports where `Foo` reports, then I want to execute a function from the `Foo::Report` that will be able to `super` the regular report.

Comment: Do you have authorship control of both `Report` and `Foo::Report`? If not, which one do you have authorship control of?

Comment: I have control over all the code, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: After @Yakov said _maybe there is a better way_I looked for a different solution, by changing the code leading up to `Report.find_by` so I can do `Foo::Report.find_by`. This solves it for me.